# Is there a global command line knit option as eval=FALSE for all chunks?

Tags: r, knitr, knitr-spin

I quite often make mistakes in the text part of *.Rmd documents and, in some cases,
fixing and running knit() implies re-running R commands that can take a while.
Therefore, it is an advantage running the .Rmd document without actually executing the R code first, then fix any typos and structure errors and then run again with evaluation.
I know this can be achieved by including

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
```

in the .Rmd

but I would prefer avoiding to actually edit the .Rmd file and using an equivalent way at the command line, something like

```
knit("file.Rmd", eval=FALSE)
```

Is actually there a way to achieve this at the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to edit the `.Rmd` file. You can just run

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
```

before running `knitr::knit()`; **knitr** will respect the global chunk options you set before calling `knitr::knit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might consider to add `cache=TRUE` to the options in knitr, that will avoid running again the code chunk again if you didn't change anything within it.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html

You can get a general effect if you add this at the beginning of the .Rmd file, like for example:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache = TRUE)
```